# TWebBrowser não carrega tiles do mapa google

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps

Tenho uma página asp que funcionava normal pelo TWebBrowser (Delphi-XE7) até hoje pela manhã, porém agora carrega todos os pontos adicionados, mas as tiles não. Se mexer no zoom carrega normal daí, mas a cada vez que atualizo vem sem

Só ocorre no win xp com ie8.

Rodei a url no navegador e ele mostra um overlay dizendo que o navegador não é mais suportado, daí retornei a version para 3, 3.18, 3.20, 3.21, 3.22 e 3.23, mas nenhuma surtiu efeito.

Até apontei para o jQuery 1.12.0 pra ver se era alguma função nova, mas também não houve efeito.

Alguma solução para este problema? Além de trocar o windows ou o ir para o TChromium, no momento não nos é possível estas duas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acredito que o seu problema seja justamente o navegador. O Twebbrowser emula o internet explorer 7 (se não me engano), vc precisa mudar no registro do windows para que essa emulação seja de acordo com o que tiver instalado, veja este: [Link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)
no meu caso eu o faço emular o Internet Explorer 11, que está bastante tranquilo em relação a compatibilidade com os recursos web atuais.

Comment: Na verdade ele não emula, ele usa com base na disponibilidade das bibliotecas encontradas na maquina onde o Delphi esta instalado! Claro, se anteriormente instalado uma versão fraca e depois uma atualizada  terá que "forçar" como você esta falando!

Comment: Então, quando falei em emulação, quis dizer que mesmo que vc tenha a versão mais atualizada ele vai rodar como a versão mais básica (que se não me engano é IE7). Vc precisa forçar para que ele rode na versão do navegador instalado, entretanto, isso pode nem resolver o seu problema pois estamos falando do IE8. Eu penei bastante quando decidi trabalhar com front-ends em html no twebbrowser por causa desse problema.

Comment: Então, ele pega a `shdocvw.dll`la na pasta System32, aqui rodando Windows8.1 ele esta usando a 6.0 '-', ou seja, é mais básico ainda do que você imagina! Mas deve resolver sim se ele usar um TWebBrowser mais moderno!

Comment: Caro Junior Moreira, na verdade o "WebBrowser" em si é um componente do Windows, e ele é implementado em várias linguagens. Mesmo que vc mude o Twebbrowser ele utilizará as configurações do sistema. Ele utiliza o Delphi XE7 ( bem mais atual que o meu XE2 :) ) e mesmo que ele instale uma versão mais nova nada mudará. Hoje todas as minhas aplicações usam o webbrowser e o front end em html5 sem nenhum problema ou comportamento estranho pq faço ele rodar como IE11.

Comment: Hoje eu uso a meta tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> e as aplicações rodam perfeitamente